# Angular 8: how can I get the index of filtered values of a table

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I'm working with Angular 8 and [ng-bootstrap's pagination component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#pagination). I wanted open a Modal with details when a tabele row is clicked and it works for unfiltered ones but after I filter the table the index is not right anymore.

For example if I have an array a=[1,2,3,4,5] and after filter the table lists for example a[2],a[3]
If I click the first element on the result, I get the a[0] instead of a[2]. 
How can i get the index of the right Element to show a modal?

A second Problem is that I dont know how to update the pagination pages instead of showing one or two result pages it shows all.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr
      *ngFor="let element of tableElements | filterTable:filterString; index as i"
      (click)="openModal(((+selectedPage-1) * +pageSize) + i)"
      >
      <td scope="row" class="text-center">
          {{ element}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Pagination -->
<ngb-pagination
  [collectionSize]="collectionSize"
  [maxSize]="6"
  [(page)]="selectedPage"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
>
</ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: Per the docs: "To add filtering or sorting on top of your pagination, you will have to update the way you split your data collection. As mentioned in Angular documentation, you don't need to reimplement dedicated pipes for that purpose. Recommendation is to move filtering and sorting logic into the component itself where some property getters could be exposed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the filtering in component code - its the most straightforward and performant way.

in component

```
allItems: SomeItems[];
filteredItems: SomeItems[];

///on some action or whatever
onFilterChange(...){
    filteredItems=allItems.filter(yourPredicates)
}
```

and in template

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of filteredItems> .....</tr>
```